# SQL join of 2 result tables

Tags: sql, join

I've created 2 SQL queries, the results are in the picture below.
In the result table 1, you can see that there are variables in the columns "lower limit" and "upper limit". Now I'd like to replace these variables with values (column "limit") of result table 2.

How can I do this?

Thank you!

[2 SQL results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKvKH.png)

I tried to user the "join" function, but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use two joins, one for the lower limit and one for the upper limit:

```sql
SELECT material, order, value, l.limit, u.limit
FROM   result1 r
JOIN   result2 l ON r.lower_limit = l.name
JOIN   result2 u ON r.upper_limit = u.name
```